# how to add the integer values using foreach in php

Tags: php

I just want to know the syntax of adding the quantity using `foreach`.
Any help is greatly appreciable.

Here is the code what I do so far:

```
$qproducts = '0';
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {  
    $qproducts .= $product['quantity'];
}       
$this->data['pquantity'] = $qproducts;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
$qproducts = 0;
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {  
    $qproducts += $product['quantity'];
}       
$this->data['pquantity'] = $qproducts;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `+` (addition) instead of `.` (concatenation).

```
$qproducts = 0;
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {  
    $qproducts += $product['quantity'];
}
```

Comment: Thanx alot Mark and Kemal. I dont know how it just skipped out of my mind.